# UITableView cell invokes UIAlertController popup ..."present" error

Tags: swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I have a tableview definition in which I am attempting to invoke an UIAlertController popup. I installed a button in the prototype tableView cell, when the button is touched, an IBAction handles the event. The problem is that the compiler won't let me.

```
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Generates compiler error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'present'

Here is the code:

```
class allListsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var cellLable:       UIView!
    @IBOutlet var cellSelected:    UILabel!
    var colorIndex = Int()        

    @IBAction func cellMarkButton(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if  colors[self.colorIndex].selected == false {
            colors[self.colorIndex].selected = true
            cellSelected.text = "•"

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "???", message: "alertA", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "dismiss", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                print("Sand: you have pressed the Dismiss button");
            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)

            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) // ERROR

        } else {
            colors[self.colorIndex].selected = false
            cellSelected.text = ""
        }
    }
```

If I comment that one line, the app runs correctly for each cell...

Comment: Simply, UITableViewCell is not a view controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling UIAlertController inside a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199716/calling-uialertcontroller-inside-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call present AlertController inside a tableView cell  , it needs a subclass of `UIViewController` or other equivalent one , you should use a delegate or some sort of notification to handle that , see my answer here for the same problem [AlertControllerCallInsideCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199716/calling-uialertcontroller-inside-a-uitableviewcell/49199783#49199783)

Edit :  Form [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) , it's an instance method inside `UIViewController` . so it can't be called inside any other class of other type (`UITableViewCell`) in your case

Comment: Thank you. I would like to learn why that is the case, can you briefly explain?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call the "present" method from a TableViewCell, I recommend having a function in the main controller to show your UIAlertController.

Using this code you can instantiate the parent driver and execute any available function:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

//UITableViewCell
if let controller = self.parentViewController as? YourController
{
    controller.showAlert()
}
```

Here is an example of its use with a CollectionViewCell:
https://github.com/AngelH2/CollectionViewCell-Comunication/tree/master/CollectionCellAction