# How to segue from UICollectionView Cell to another ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Assume I have a user cell. I need to start a ChatViewController for this User. So, I have UICollectionView which presented as raws (1 cell = 1 row). How to segue to ChatViewController from cell?

I don't use InterfaceBuilder at all. Only through code way.

I planned to use **didSelectItemAt** but I don't have enough swift programming skills to figure out how to use this function for my purpose. When I try to write **prepare for segue** or **performSegue with Identifier** inside didSelectItemAt function the Xcode doesn't provide proper autocomplete. My Code is below:

```
import UIKit

class MyList: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super .init(frame: frame)
        setUpLocalizedUserList()

    }


    //Click on User Cell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Click")

    }


    //Localized User List (Collection View)
    private func setUpLocalizedUserList(){
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 80)

        let userListFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width), height: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height) - 160)
        let myCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: userListFrame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.register(LocalizedUserCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "userCell")
        myCollectionView.register(GroupChatCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        addSubview(myCollectionView)
    }

    //Number of Section in User List
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    //Lists' Sizes
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (section == 0) ? 5 : 4
    }

    //Cells content here
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! LocalizedUserCell
            return cell
        }else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as! GroupChatCell
            return cell
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Maybe it's important - my users cells are inside another cell.

Comment: You can performSegue() only from a UIViewController, not a UIView. So you need to find a way (closure, delegate, notification) that your cell tells the UIViewController showing it that it needs to performSegue() (with potentially some param)

Comment: I'm trying to use delegation pattern, but I can't understand how to pass delegate variable from my UIViewController which can use those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a segue from inSide collectionViewCell as present func needs a UIViewController , see here my answer for a table cell , the same logic  [TableCellNavigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199716/calling-uialertcontroller-inside-a-uitableviewcell/49199783#49199783)

Comment: Thank you! Your links and answers were right. The delegate pattern is the right way for me.