# Present alert controller from table view cell across multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view cell with a button. When that button is clicked, I want to present an alert controller. What I have implemented now is a delegate pattern, like the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199783/6724161

The problem is that I use this table view cell across my app in multiple view controllers, so I don't want to copy and paste the same alert controller code to each view controller.

How can I present an alert controller on any view controller when the button in the table view cell is clicked?

Comment: you must check out the notification pattern to achieve this use.

Comment: @elia I'm not sure how a notification pattern would provide me the ability to present to a view controller

Comment: Its not for presenting any controller, its for listening any notification form Living cell or controller and way to generalize it as you describe if I don’t get it wrong

Comment: I am writing an answer as I mentioned about notification. So there can be a good way to mix somethings.

Answer (score 4):

You could use notifications, as pointed out in the comments, but I would do something else.

**1.** In your custom cell class, I would add a property called `parentVC` of type `UIViewController`:

```swift
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var parentVC: UIViewController!

    ...

}
```

**2.** Then, when you are dequeueing the cell, I would set the cell's `parentVC` to `self`, like so:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier") as! YourTableViewCell
    //`self` is the view controller that the cell's table view is held in
    cell.parentVC = self
    return cell
}
```

**3.** Finally, whenever your custom cell's button is clicked, simply present the alert controller from `parentVC`:

```swift
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var parentVC: UIViewController!

    @IBAction func customButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your alert title.", message: "Your alert message.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        parentVC.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    ...

}
```

**Another variation (as suggested by rmaddy)**

You could simply change the button within your `UITableViewCell` to recursively check the next responder until it is of type `UIViewController`.

First add the following extension to `UIView`. This will find the `UIView`'s parent view controller:

```swift
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

You could simply change the button within your `UITableViewCell` to recursively check the next responder until it is of type `UIViewController`. Once you find this `UIViewController`, you can have it present the `UIAlertController`, or any other view controller:

Source: [Given a view, how do I get its viewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372977/given-a-view-how-do-i-get-its-viewcontroller=)

Once you find this `UIViewController`, you can have it present the `UIAlertController`, or any other view controller:

```swift
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    ...

    @IBAction func customButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your alert title.", message: "Your alert message.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        guard let parentVC = self.parentViewController else { return }   
        parentVC.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Or simply have the cell find its own view controller by walking the responder chain. Then you don't even need to have each view controller set itself on each cell.

Comment: So recursively check a `UIView`'s next responder until it is a `UIViewController`? Like in mxcl's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372977/given-a-view-how-do-i-get-its-viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

Your can present using AppDelegates window property.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(action)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Better you have a validation based on your application rootViewController type to avoid 
issues. For example,

- if the rootViewController is a navigationController, you can take the top viewController of the navigationController and present the alert.
- if the rootViewController is UIViewController, your can present directly from the rootViewController.

Comment: This won't work if the root view controller is already presenting a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with using `Notification` pattern.

Firstly I highly recommend to build your notification diagram with extend a `Notification.Name` for your alert stuff.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let notificationForAlertingStuff = Notification.Name("isAlertReallyAlert")
}
```

Then create an observer notification for alert stuff.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveData(_:)), name: Notification.Name("isAlertReallyAlert"), object: nil)
}
```

Create your own notification handler function.

```
@objc private func onDidReceiveData(_ notification: NSNotification){
        print("notification has fired. user info => \(notification.userInfo) ")

      // present alert
    }
```

I think you must extend `UIViewController` and add a simple function for alerting with getting `title` and `description` parameters. For now there is just printing info from the `Notification.`

Then when you fire any Notification use this function in button click or row click.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        var alertData = ["title": "Alert Title", "description": "Alert Description"]

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("isAlertReallyAlert"), object: self, userInfo: alertData)
    }
```

So maybe you can specified and add feature for user info to prepare any alert.

Lastly here is the extension for the `UIViewController` to use `UIAlertController` `efficiently`.

```
extension UIViewController{


    func shotAlert(title:String, description:String){
        // Create Alert Controller

    }

}
```

// GOOD POINT:

Let's assume your view controllers `A, B and C` are living in `UINavigationController` stack like `A -> B -> C`, so if you add observer in A controller you can fire any notification from the C as you describe `Notification.Name` correctly.

Comment: Why do you create a static `Notification.Name` but then never use it?

Comment: Also note that the question is about a table cell needing to display an alert without the need of replicating alert related code in every view controller that happens to use that cell class. This answer doesn't address that at all.

Comment: @rmaddy It can be used as Notification.Name.staticVariable or like I used describing way. Another your comment, so I just extend UIViewCpntroller to exact alert function, just can use it every UITableViewCells inside with Notification I think and that’s way of I address it. Opposition to David’s answer I am not thinking / want to  to send any UIViewController reference for making easy for it, in my solution it can be used like above I think